# Volatile or Synchronized in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, volatile

We have a class CalcStrategySet, which is accessed in a concurrent environment by multiple threads. I was wondering if you guys can advise which implementation is better from the 2 listed below. In the first one I have declared the variables as volatile and made the flip method, which is atomic operation as Synchronized. Other implementation I have not declared the variables as volatile but made all other methods as synchronized.

Do these methods serve the purpose and not result in race condition and if yes then which one is better?

**WITH VOLATILE & SYNCHRONIZED ATOMIC METHOD**

```
public class CalcStrategySet {
   private volatile CalcStrategy current;
   private volatile CalcStrategy backup;
   private volatile boolean isBackup;

   public CalcStrategySet(CalcStrategy current, CalcStrategy backup) {
       this.current = current;
       this.backup = backup;
   }

   public void isStandard() {
       return !isBackup;
   }
  
   public void merge(CalcStrategy other) {
      current.merge(other);
   }

   public synchronized void flip() {
      if(!isBackup) {
          current = backup;
          backup = null;
          isBackup = true;
      } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Already in backup mode");
      }
   }
}
```

**FULLY SYNCHRONIZED**

```
public class CalcStrategySet {
   private CalcStrategy current;
   private CalcStrategy backup;
   private boolean isBackup;

   public CalcStrategySet(CalcStrategy current, CalcStrategy backup) {
       this.current = current;
       this.backup = backup;
   }

   public synchronized void isStandard() {
       return !isBackup;
   }
  
   public synchronized void merge(CalcStrategy other) {
      current.merge(other);
   }

   public synchronized void flip() {
      if(!isBackup) {
          current = backup;
          backup = null;
          isBackup = true;
      } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Already in backup mode");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In your first implementation, nothing prevents a situation where thread 1 (T1) is in `flip` method, finds `isBackup` is false, and right after T2 enters the `merge` method and modifies `current`. Sometimes T2 will do that before `current = backup`, sometimes after. This may or may not be an issue for your use case. Also, if `CalcStrategy` is not thread safe, the `merge` method could be an issue if it is not synchronized.

Comment: @assylias I would say 1st implementation successfully meets two (implicit) invariants (1) no concurrent flip (2) current strategy is used until replaced with backup. If it is all OP needs then 1st implementation is fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Do these methods serve the purpose and not result in race condition and if yes then which one is better?

It's hard to determine this without knowing fully how the class is used as well as what the `CalcStrategy.merge()` method does.  If the `merge()` is reentrant already then the first mechanism seems adequate.  There are certainly race conditions that may mean that the current gets updated right before the `flip(...)` method gets to the switch.

The worry is that the `flip(...)` method might move to the backup but have not switched `isBackup` to be true.  For example, one thread could be in the middle of `flip(...)`, the current has been set to the backup, but another thread might still see `isStandard()` returning true because `isBackup` has not been set yet.  This is exacerbated with the multiple `volatile` fields.

A way to improve this would be to use an `AtomicReference` for the `current`.  That would reduce that race condition and means that `flip()` doesn't need to be `synchronized`.  In the below code, `standard` and `backup` are final and not `volatile`.  Not sure if that breaks something.  There still is the chance that `isStandard()` gets called right before `flip()` makes the change but it is an improvement.

Something like:

```
private final AtomicReference<CalcStrategy> current = new AtomicReference<>();
private final CalcStrategy standard;
private final CalcStrategy backup;
// no boolean

public CalcStrategySet(CalcStrategy standard, CalcStrategy backup) {
    this.current.set(standard);
    this.standard = standard;
    this.backup = backup;
}

public void isStandard() {
    // no race with isBackup set in flip()
    return (current.get() == standard);
}

// no need for synchronized because one single atomic operation
public void flip() {
   // update to the backup atomically
   if(!current.compareAndSet(standard, backup)) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Already in backup mode");
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example code must also store the construction argument `standard` in a separate field, for example the `standard` field that you access in the method implementations.

Comment: The `flip()` method can still change `current`, _after_ `isStandard()` fetched its value and _before_ its comparison with `standard`, causing `isStandard()` to return the "wrong" value. That means your biggest worry can still happen, though less likely. Fortunately, the worry never represents an inconsistent state of the `CalcStrategySet` object itself: it is not a race condition. 
Though I prefer your atomic solution, the original first implementation with volatiles is  good enough if the calling-site of `isStandard` is aware that it can return a stale picture.

Comment: There are still race conditions @Emmef but there is not a double field issue here.  Either standard has been updated when it is tested or it hasn't.  `isStandard()` can never return the wrong value as long as `current.get()` is called after `current.compareAndSet(...)`.

Comment: Added back the `standard` field.  Thanks.